# How to select recently appeded element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom, select, append

I want to select recently created element doing something like this:

```
$("body").append("<div id='popup.dialog'></div>");
dialogDiv = $("#popup.dialog");
```

But after execution of this dialogDiv contains nothing. 
So is there're way to select newly createn element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot is not valid in the ID. `#popup.dialog` searches for `<div id='popup' class='dialog'>`. You should replace it with a dash, like

```
$("body").append("<div id='popup-dialog'></div>");
dialogDiv = $("#popup-dialog");
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) Dont use periods in your ids

2) you could do it like this a bit better:

```
var dialogDiv =$('<div id="popup-dialog"></div>').appendTo('body');
```

At this point you could chain more, or just use the `dialogDiv` variable.

This stops you from taking a performance hit by selecting an element that you already have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the `.` in the id.

The reason is, that jQuery used the `.` to match classes, so you are looking for an element with id = popup and class = dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `.` in an id.

Try this:

```
$("body").append("<div id='popup-dialog'></div>");
dialogDiv = $("#popup-dialog");
```